# Cannot find application on Play store from a Galaxy Tab 2 7''

Tags: android, google-play

I am developping an Android application which is deployed to Play Store. Unfortunaly, I cannot find it from a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7'' though it works fine on a Xperia Tablet Z. 
I get the following output from aapt dump badging command :

```
package: name='myapp' versionCode='10045' versionName='1.0.45-SNAPSHOT' platformBuildVers
ionName=''
install-location:'auto'
application-label:'MyApp'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png'
application: label='MyApp' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-debuggable
launchable-activity: name='myapp.activity'  label='MyApp' icon=''
sdkVersion:'14'
targetSdkVersion:'19'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CALL_PHONE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission: name='myapp.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feature for all apps'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320' '480'
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I might miss ?

Comment: what is the android version of your Samsung Galaxy Tab 7''??

Comment: Do you have any setting for which all devices are supported and which all are excluded. Did you check the list there ?

Comment: The tablet's Android version is 4.1.2. Which seems ok with my android manifest.